# Break points on QtCreator are ignored?

Tags: debugging, qt, breakpoints

I set a break point, I debug the application (I don't run it, I'm not confused with what 'run it' and what 'debug it' is and how these differ between them) but Qt outputs this message:
http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/1272/debug.png

and completely ignores my breakpoints while in the previous version it didn't and it used to work just fine...

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two modes is that in "Run It", QtCreator just runs the application without any sort of debugging attached. In "Debug It", QtCreator attaches a debugger (usually GDB) to the application. In order to use your breakpoints, you must click "Debug It". Additionally, your target must be set to debug in your project file. My guess is that currently is says "release". Change this to debug and then rebuild your project. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to Build >> Open Build / Run target selector and setting your application to build on debug and not release?

If your application build is set to build then there'll be code optimization and your breakpoints by line numbers will mean nothing.

Comment: @under_zero I am having the same problem as you - what exactly do you mean? I understand the fact that you're working with env vars, but what is `PATH Debug`?